# Selecting the columns from source file based on control file

Tags: shell-script, awk, gawk

I have requirement where I need to construct a file based on control file.
The first row of my source file contains column names. The control file contains the columns which I need to output into a file

Source file:

```
ename|eid|emanger|esal|city|deptid|deptname
peter|10|larry|$2000|melbourne|20|electronics
shaun|11|Peter|$1000|sydney|20|electronics
```

Control file:

```
ename
eid
esal
ecity
```

o/p -- we need output only the columns which are there in the control file and the column order should be the same as in the control file.

Sample Output:

```
ename|eid|esal|ecity
peter|10|$2000|melbourne
shaun|11|$1000|sydney
```

Comment: No - the separate control file makes it more complicated.  If it were a one-liner, someone would be certain to paste in an "answer".  But it looks more than that...

Comment: Seems like the separator is what making it a bit complicated. But I think there is a way. working on it. Let see

Comment: see dupplicate, along with `-F="\|"` as awk arguement

Comment: By the way, your source file has a heading of `city`, but your control file specifies `ecity`.